# jQuery slider with content

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to ask you, how to do the icons menu with slider. So I mean how to have this content slider to move in more html contents.
Example [www.tapmates.com](http://tapmates.com) (the apps menu).

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of the site you see the desired effect on? It'll hold the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often referred to as the [Coda slider](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/), after the [Coda](http://panic.com/coda) site by Panic, but it's found in [many other guises](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

I've actually made one which we currently use at work on our mobile pages. It slides whatever content you put inside the "frames".

You can check it out here - http://dezignhero.github.io/swiper/

It's designed primarily for webkit devices and recognizes touch swipe gestures, but also works on desktop too.